# Reading Mnist Data

Tags: java, mnist

I have a problem reading mnist data. The first thing that i should get is a magic number - 2049 in case of labels, but when i read the file and print the first number it's something different. I've tried different ways to read file, the number is always the same but it's not 2049 (It's 529205256).

When I try to read images file the first number is the same (529205256). Is that some number from .gz file extension? What am I doing wrong here?

```
Path tempPath = Paths.get("res/mnist-labels.gz");
byte[] test = Files.readAllBytes(tempPath);
ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(test);
System.out.println(Integer.toString(buffer1.getInt()));
```

EDIT: Turns out i just had to unpack those files -.-

Comment: You need to unpack it first

Comment: @Andronicus yeah... i acutally realised it the moment i pressed the button to add the post. So here i was wondering for like an hour why it doesn't work